# What does it mean by 'relative luxury' and 'hand person' in idiomatic English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

[Source](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/ipl/news/Delhi-Daredevils-hope-to-hit-home-stride-vs-KKR/articleshow/52050452.cms?)

> This is a relative luxury, as the ones still around in the team set-up will attest, given the team's abysmal run of the last few seasons.

I could not figure out what the speaker intends to say here.

> Gambhir is an old Kotla hand who is unlikely to misread his 'home' patch.

What does it mean by 'hand person'?

> On the other hand, while Chris Morris' manic hitting lower down against Gujarat would have given DD's finishing hopes a boost,....

Does 'His hitting lower down the order has given hopes...' require a comma before 'has'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence

> This is a relative luxury, as the ones still around in the team set-up will attest, given the team's abysmal run of the last few seasons.

is in reference to the constant the management style of the Delhi Daredevils a couple paragraphs later.  Management likes to constantly change players on the team, but your sentence points to the fact that things have stabilised, for now.

The sentence

> Gambhir is an old Kotla hand who is unlikely to misread his 'home' patch.

means Gautam Gambler is very familiar with the pitch at the Feroz Shah Kotla grounds, this is in reference to modifications that were being made before the T20 match.

A comma is not required before "has".

Answer (score 1):

"A relative luxury" means that the situation is comfortable ("luxurious") compared to something else - presumably, to the situation earlier.

"An old hand" is an idiom meaning "an experienced person". There is no phrase "A hand person".

I don't understand the third question, as your sentence is quite different from the example you quote.